# Automapper ObservableCollection – refreshing is not working

Tags: automapper

I have small WPF application. There are 5 projects in solution.

I want separate DOMAIN classes with UI ENTITIES and I want to use AUTOMAPPER.

You can download whole solution here: [TestWPFAutomapper.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nj2794ano4i1gx/TestWPFAutomapper.zip)

Domain class(Domain.Source.cs) with UI Entity(Entities.Destination.cs) have same signature.

In Entities.Destination.cs I would like to put other logic.

```
namespace DOMAIN
{
    public class Source
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
    } 
}


using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ENITITIES
{
    public class Destination : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private int _id;
        private int _position;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        public int Position
        {
            get { return _position; }
            set
            {
                _position = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Position");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My data comes from DAL.DataContext using Entity Framework with CodeFirst. Here I´m using Source class.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using DOMAIN;

namespace DAL
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Source> Sources { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mapping is in BL.MyAppLogic.cs . In this class I have property Items which is ObservableCollection.

After puting another item into DB for Source class collection get refresh but for Destination is not refreshing.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using DAL;
using DOMAIN;
using ENITITIES;

namespace BL
{
    public class MyAppLogic
    {
        private readonly DataContext _dataContext = new DataContext();
        public ObservableCollection<Source> Items { get; set; }
        //public ObservableCollection<Destination> Items { get; set; }

        public MyAppLogic()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
            Mapping();

            _dataContext.Sources.Load();
            Items = _dataContext.Sources.Local;
            //Items = Mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<Source>, ObservableCollection<Destination>>(_dataContext.Sources.Local);
        }

        private void Mapping()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ReverseMap();
            // I tried also Mapper.CreateMap<ObservableCollection<Source>, ObservableCollection<Destination>>().ReverseMap();
        }

        public int GetLastItem()
        {
            return _dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select Position from Sources").ToList().LastOrDefault();
        }

        public void AddNewItem(Destination newItem)
        {
            _dataContext.Sources.Add(Mapper.Map<Destination, Source>(newItem));
            _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is not with mapping, that’s works good, but with refreshing collection after adding or removing items from db. If I use DOMAIN.Source class everything works, collection is refreshing. But when I’m using ENTITIES.Destination data comes from DB and also I can put som new data to DB but refresing ObservableCollection is not working.

Please try to comment lines(14 & 23) in BL.MyAppLogic.cs  and uncomment(15 & 24) and you’ll see what I mean.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it but I don´t know if is correct.

Local has CollectionChanged event

so in constructor I put these lines

```
public MyAppLogic()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
            Mapping();

            _dataContext.Sources.Load();

            _dataContext.Sources.Local.CollectionChanged += SourcesCollectionChanged;

            Items = Mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<Source>, ObservableCollection<Destination>>(_dataContext.Sources.Local);

        }
```

and handler looks

```
private void SourcesCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = sender as ObservableCollection<Source>;

            Mapper.Map(source, Items);
        }
```

Now is my collection automating refreshing when I put something to DB in my UI.
Looks like automapper don´t put reference into Items, but create new instance.